# ffmpeg file doesn't exist, but file exists and path is correct

Tags: node.js, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error even though the files exists and the path is correct
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KigS9.png)

Here is the code I have

```
// initialize imports
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path

// initialize paths for ffmpeg
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath)

// export merge function
module.exports.merge = async () => {
  await ffmpeg('./viral.mp4')
    .input('./rand_gta.mp4')
    .complexFilter([
      `[0:v]scale=576:1024[0scaled]`,
      `[1:v]scale=576:512[1scaled]`,
      `[0scaled]pad=576:1024[0padded]`,
      `[0padded][1scaled]overlay=0:550[output]`,
    ])
    .outputOptions(['-map 0:a', '-map [output]'])
    .output('./out.mp4')
    .on('error', function (er) {
      console.log('error occured: ' + er.message)
    })
    .on('progress', ({ percent }) => {
      const value = percent.toFixed(2)
      console.log(`Processing video: ${value}%`)
    })
    .run()
}
```

Any feedback, help. is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Change the path from relative to absolute and check if the code works correctly. If it works, then your relative path is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by moving the video files in the root directory. the code now looks like this:

```
await ffmpeg('./content/viral.mp4')
.input('./content/rand_gta.mp4')
```

and the file structure is now:

```
root
 |__content
    |__viral.mp4
    |__rand_gta.mp4
```